How can I prevent LinkedIn from changing language when I visit a profile in another country?
I have my language settings in LinkedIn set to English.
When I search for people and I click on the links for their profile, if the profile is in another country LinkedIn (e.g. France or Sweden), LinkedIn changes the language of the UI from English to that language, which is very annoying. And it is sticky, that is even if I later go to my own profile page or settings and ..., the UI is still in the non-English language.

Is there a way to stop this from happening? I don't want the language of my UI up change to another language when I visit profiles from other countries.

If not, how can I report this bug to LinkedIn folks? I searched a bit but cannot find how to report bugs like this to them.


